# SQL - How to test the existence of a specific value in a ARRAY<STRUCT<value STRING>>

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, where-clause

For a SQL Query I need to SELECT the rows that have a specific value in their "tags" array.
I am a full beginner in SQL but I feel that I de not find good documentation on it.

I tried:

`SELECT tags FROM [my_database] WHERE tags.value = "something"`

> Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT>

and

`SELECT * FROM [my_database] WHERE tags = "something"`

> No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT>, STRING. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY

My database says that : tags is a record (array of string) and value a string.

The result I want is a **list of all rows that contains a specific value in their tags array**.

I feel that the answer is really easy... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a good answer, but I'll give you the following one anyway:

For example **[my_database]** has tables like: **table1, table2, table3, table4** and these tables all have a **tags field**. I suggest you the following one

```
SELECT tags FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT tags FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT tags FROM table3
UNION ALL
SELECT tags FROM table4
WHERE tags = "something";
```

Comment: Indeed it is not the answer I waited for but thanks. I work in the same table and not with many..

Comment: Try like then:
`SELECT tags FROM [my_database] WHERE tags LIKE "%something%";`
and here is a link where I studied sql, it can help you on sql : [sql.sh](https://sql.sh/) .
and here is for the LIKE in sql : 
[like](https://sql.sh/cours/where/like)

Comment: thanks for the links. I tried your answer (already tried it) but I have an error. 
"No matching signature for operator LIKE for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<value STRING>>, STRING. Supported signatures: STRING LIKE STRING; BYTES LIKE BYTES at [1:53]"